# Is in the area where the aurora's are also more cosmic ray?

Tags: particle-physics

On our poles the aurora's are the effect of high energy particles and photons comming from the sun (solarwind) and of cosmic ray. Those rays are interacting with the oxygen and nitrogen molecules/atoms in the air and by these collisions there are more different particles created (extended air shower (EAS)) like muons, pions and kaons.

Now the aurora's are happening high in the sky at 80 to 1000 km altitude. But isn't some of the high energetic particles and photons of the cosmic ray or solarwind also comming on earth near the poles. So perhaps you can say that going to look at the aurora's in the polearea's could be dangeres due to harmfull radiation?

Answer (score -1):

Most of this radiation is scattered away from the earth, leaving the atmospheric particles ionised. This causes the aurora. Although the radiation levels are higher near the poles, it is not deadly because of the scattering.